# Tricky seg fault in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gdb, fault

I'm trying to run a C project for my university assignment and I've hit a seg fault on the line "while (current->next != NULL) {" in the following code segment:

```
FILE* f = fileOpen("test.txt");
if (f != NULL){
    functionList = fileReadToMemory(f, &graphParams);//functionList is a pointer to the first value of the linked list it creates
    current = functionList;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d %d %d %s", current->red, current->green, current->blue, current->expression);//Prints value of linked list
        current = current -> next;
    }
}
```

The error that gdb gives me is as follows:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000000000003a
0x0000000100000b30 in main () at main.c:23
23          while (current->next != NULL) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

You need to do

```
while (current != NULL)
```

instead of

```
current->next != NULL
```

since the last element in the list will cause segfault.

Comment: .. which, almost as a side effect, then will also function correctly if the returned `functionList` happened to be `NULL`.

Comment: yes, in that case, the head of the linked list is null, so the while (current != NULL) can be interpreted to mean "does the linked list have anymore elements?"

Comment: yes, in that case, the head of the linked list is null.  So effectively, a NULL value is still a valid linked list, just that it is an empty linked list. So the while (current != NULL) can be interpreted to mean "does the linked list have anymore elements?", and it works on linked lists of any size, even 0.